# Arch linux: custom repo: File is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (checksum))

Tags: manjaro, pacman, signature, makepkg

I created a custom repository on my manjaro machine (to make a custom Manjaro ISO) with adding:

```py
[manjaro-mate-aur-packages]
SigLevel = Never
Server = https://github.com/FreaxMATE/manjaro-mate-aur-packages/blob/main/manjaro-mate-aur-packages/x86_64/manjaro-mate-aur-packages.db.tar.gz?raw=true
```

to `pacman.conf`.

`sudo pacman -Syu` runs without any issues:

```
:: Synchronising package databases...
 core                                       172,1 KiB   637 KiB/s 00:00 [########################################] 100%
 extra                                     1903,1 KiB  1710 KiB/s 00:01 [########################################] 100%
 community                                    6,7 MiB  1883 KiB/s 00:04 [########################################] 100%
 multilib                                   177,2 KiB  1441 KiB/s 00:00 [########################################] 100%
 manjaro-mate-aur-packages                    2,5 KiB  7,11 KiB/s 00:00 [########################################] 100%
```

When I try to install a package from this repo I get this error:

```
:: Retrieving packages...
 mate-layouts-0.0.5-2-any                     2,5 KiB  21,6 KiB/s 00:00 [########################################] 100%
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                          [########################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                        [########################################] 100%
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mate-layouts-0.0.5-2-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (checksum)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] 
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (checksum))
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

although I set `SigLevel = Never`. Do I have to sign the packages when creating them with `buildpkg`? If that is the case how do I add them to the Manjaro custom ISO?

I used this doc:
https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Buildiso_with_AUR_packages:_Using_buildpkg and https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Build_Manjaro_ISOs_with_buildiso

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `Server` line. You are pointing to the db file of the repo. It should be pointed to the repo instead. What pacman is downloading is `https://github.com/FreaxMATE/manjaro-mate-aur-packages/blob/main/manjaro-mate-aur-packages/x86_64/manjaro-mate-aur-packages.db.tar.gz?raw=true/mate-layouts-0.0.5-2-any.pkg.tar.zst`, which clearly doesn't exists and instead download a 404 error page. Also, you should use the `raw` URL instead of `blob`, because `blob` URL refers to HTML pages of the package, rather than actual package. The server URL should be changed to `https://github.com/FreaxMATE/manjaro-mate-aur-packages/raw/main/manjaro-mate-aur-packages/$arch` instead. Also, still it is unuseable because the db and file files are symlinked to their compressed forms which are represented as text file in git, so when downloading they aren't actually pointed to, ratehr downloads a plaintext file which reads `manjaro-mate-aur-packages.db.tar.gz` and `manjaro-mate-aur-packages.file.tar.gz` respectively. You should file an issue.

**Edit**:
Tested with my own fork

```
[manjaro-mate-aur-packages]
SigLevel = Never
Server = https://github.com/abdullah-if/manjaro-mate-aur-packages/raw/main/manjaro-mate-aur-packages/x86_64
```

Output:

```
$ sudo pacman -Swd manjaro-mate-aur-packages/caja-admin
resolving dependencies...

Packages (11) caja-1.26.0-1  exempi-2.5.2-1  gcr-3.40.0-1  gvfs-1.48.1-1  libcddb-1.3.2-6.1
              libcdio-2.1.0-2.1  libcdio-paranoia-10.2+2.0.1-2.1  mate-desktop-1.26.0-1
              python-caja-1.26.0-1  startup-notification-0.12-7  caja-admin-0.0.5-1

Total Download Size:  0.02 MiB

:: Proceed with download? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
 caja-admin-0.0.5-1-any           18.8 KiB  9.79 KiB/s 00:02 [--------------------------------] 100%
(11/11) checking keys in keyring                             [--------------------------------] 100%
(11/11) checking package integrity                           [--------------------------------] 100%
```

No error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `https://github.com/FreaxMATE/manjaro-mate-aur-packages/blob/main/manjaro-mate-aur-packages/x86_64/manjaro-mate-aur-packages.db.tar.gz?raw=true/mate-layouts-0.0.5-2-any.pkg.tar.zst` exists. The packages are also recognized and can be downloaded, but the signing issue persists.

Comment: @FreaxMATE ok, fair point. But do you know what it downloads ? The db, instead of the  pkg.

Comment: @FreaxMATE see edit.